# Error using the Apple Dev code?

Tags: ios

I just copied/pasted this code from the apple dev libary into xcode, and xcode gives me a lot of basic syntax errors..

```
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
         if (viewController != nil)
         {
             [self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController
         }
         else if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
         {
             [self authenticatedPlayer: localPlayer];
         }
         else
         {
             [self disableGameCenter];
         }
     }];
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you building for ios6? The @property authenticateHandler is not available in earlier versions of the OS according to the docs

Comment: That code is taken directly from the docs, which is for iOS6, here's the link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Users/Users.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH8-SW6

Comment: Right but in XCode, under target>summary>deployment target are you targeting ios6?

Comment: I wasn't, but I am now, and still same error. Xcode says that an "]" is missing.

Comment: oh I see it. right after [self showAuthenticationDialogWhenReasonable: viewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you need to be targeting iOS6 and are not. My compiler also generates errors if I target iOS 5.x. Docs state that availability of the @property authenticateHandler is iOS6  only.

Also, syntax error missing closing bracket and semicolon after viewController in the first if clause of the block.

Comment: In the build settings it says latest SDK (iOS6), this might be an odd thing to say, but are there any typos in it, xcode says there is an "]" missing.